# How to delay an event in discord py rewrite without using time.sleep

Tags: python, time, discord, discord.py

The section of my code looks like -

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message)
  member = message.author
  role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="name")
  await member.add_roles(role)
  time.sleep(100)
  await member.remove_roles(role)
```

So this, of course, does not work for the intended purpose as while the bot is sleeping it is unable to take any other commands, and therefore interact with other members trying to attain the role.

Is there a way to make discord.py wait a set amount of time - in my case a month - before executing the succeeding code (which in my case removes the role it previously set)?

Comment: You actually could use the Time module if you were to also use threading. You could have multiple threads, one running the timed event and the other running your main script :)

Comment: You can use `await asyncio.sleep(100)` https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#sleeping